# Windows Subsystem for Linux のubuntu起動時のメッセージ

Tags: ubuntu, wsl

起動時に以下のメッセージが出るようになってしまいました。
パスの問題？のようなのですがどうしたらでないようにできるのかわかりません。

```sh
rt: Unknown command 'PATH=~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Program Files/CMake/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Calibre2:/mnt/c/Ruby21-x64/bin:/mnt/c/Users/adminryzen/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/snap/bin'.
rt: For help, run 'rt help'.
```

Comment: おそらく表示されてるメッセージは [rt-client-cli/script/rt#L163-L164](https://github.com/bestpractical/rt-client-cli/blob/94dc79fa2b7b40e43e32576ef8f5fe59139de0c2/script/rt#L163-L164)  かもしれませんが、何かをインストール、または何かのドキュメントに沿って作業した結果、起動時に `rt PATH=$PATH`  のようなコマンドが実行されるようになったと思います。より詳細な環境の情報(Windowsのバージョンなど)と最近行った作業を **質問文に追記**  すると回答が得られるかもしれません。

Comment: 起動時に自動実行されるファイルに記述ミスがありそうです。ホームディレクトリ（起動直後のディレクトリ）で`ls -a`を実行すると隠しファイル（`.`で始まるファイル）が表示されるので、`.bashrc`や`.profile`や`.bash_profile`があれば、それぞれの内容を質問文に追記すると、原因がわかるかもしれません。

Comment: `rt` コマンドが書かれてる場所を探すだけなら、 `grep -Hn 'rt PATH' /etc/profile ~/.profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile` の結果を貼って頂ければいいですね( `.bash_profile` が存在しない場合は、引数から外してください)。大抵の場合、 `PATH=foo:$PATH`  か `PATH=$PATH:bar` みたいに書かれること多いので、 `rbenv`  か `/snap/bin`  が原因な気もしますが。